# Find and return value

Tags: vba, find, return

I have following description in cell P194 ,P200 , P300, and so on.

"Cut-off Cost| INV # CAT-02345-BAT-MAT07| Line # 00785| SEQ # 719779| Billing MUG STC4500"

I want all the character after `INV #` till `|` and the character between `INV #` and `|` is not fixed, it differs. I am using the code below. The script is working fine for INV # items in column P, But not for non INV # description in Column P. like cell P12 description is "GLUCO30|57891|||||M007Z|13/15 Local Host CDFS|CATT-4FGH548-20121220|||00013|FICO56D2F0G0G0|
". It is printing the value in cell A12 as "S-427548-20121220"
For better understanding the issue please paste both the description in Column P and run the below code.
Descrition in Cloumn P
1)"Cut-off Cost| INV # CAT-02345-BAT-MAT07| Line # 00785| SEQ # 719779| Billing MUG STC4500"
2)"GLUCO30|57891|||||M007Z|13/15 Local Host CDFS|CATT-4FGH548-20121220|||00013|FICO56D2F0G0G0|

```
    Sub Invoice()
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim RowCtr As Long, MyStart As Long, MyEnd As Long
    RowCtr = 6
    While Sheets("Stack").Range("E" & RowCtr).Value <> ""
        MyStart = WorksheetFunction.Find("#", Sheets("stack").Range("P" & RowCtr).Value, 1)
        MyEnd = WorksheetFunction.Find("|", Sheets("stack").Range("P" & RowCtr).Value, MyStart)
        If WorksheetFunction.Find("#", Sheets("stack").Range("P" & RowCtr).Value, 1) > 0 Then
            Sheets("stack").Range("A" & RowCtr).Value = Mid(Sheets("stack").Range("P" & RowCtr).Value _
            , MyStart + 2, MyEnd - MyStart - 2)
        End If
        RowCtr = RowCtr + 1
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: How do you know what portion of the second string is the number you want?

Comment: Postion of the string differs the only catch is starts with INV # and end with |.

Comment: Is there always going to be only one # sign in the string?  If so have you tried the solution I posted below?  If there is more than one you could modify it to find the whole `INV #` and work from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub changeString(sample As String)
    ' Find the location of the first # and remove that portion
    Dim charNum As Integer
    charNum = InStr(1, sample, "#")
    sample = Right(sample, Len(sample) - charNum )

    ' Remove everything from the | till the end
    charNum = InStr(1, sample, "|")
    sample = Left(sample, charNum - 1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to split the string by delimiter | or use regex

```
Option Explicit

Sub Method1()
Dim testString As String
Dim splitArr() As String
Dim i As Long

testString = "Cut-off Cost| INV # CAT-02345-BAT-MAT07| Line # 00785| SEQ # 719779| Billing MUG STC4500"
splitArr = Split(testString, "|")
For i = LBound(splitArr, 1) To UBound(splitArr, 1)
    If InStr(1, splitArr(i), "INV #", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        Debug.Print Trim(Replace(splitArr(i), "INV #", vbNullString))
    End If
Next i

End Sub

Sub Method2()
Dim testString As String
Dim regex As Object
Dim regexMatches As Object

    testString = "Cut-off Cost| INV # CAT-02345-BAT-MAT07| Line # 00785| SEQ # 719779| Billing MUG STC4500"

    Set regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    With regex
        .MultiLine = False
        .Global = False
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "INV #[\s\S]+?\|"
    End With
    Set regexMatches = regex.Execute(testString)
    Debug.Print Trim(Replace(Replace(regexMatches(0), "INV #", vbNullString), "|", vbNullString))


End Sub
```